# Collapsed grid fields have no labels

Tags: grid, admin, publish-layout

I have a situation where our client is going to be adding dozens of grid rows in their entries. They need to be able to collapsed and re-order these grid rows. However, once collapsed, there is no way to indicate which row contains what data, which row is which period. They can't really re-oder them with the rows not collapsed, as they're much too tall.

[image]

How might I make this easier for them? Is there a different field type I should look at, or is the only way to build a custom extension for them?

Any thoughts or ideas, or what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently no first party solution to this. I added a [feature request](https://github.com/ExpressionEngine/ExpressionEngine/discussions/3262) for this a while ago and it has not been resolved yet.

Another option would be to use a third party builder such as bloqs and creating a relationship field type for the content.